# Is mutual_friend_count deprecated in FQL starting OpenGraph v2.0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

The mutualfriends connection for users is deprecated in OpenGraph v2.0, however it should still work with OpenGraph v1.0 for another year.

I would expect the FQL [mutual_friends_count](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) field to work for anthor year as well. However, it seems like it is no longer supported (returns null).

Anybody knows if it is just a bug, or if it is by design?

Comment: It's an open bug report for V1.0 here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242368225968716/
For V2.0 i believe it should only be returning friends who also use the app making the call

Comment: @igy Thanks, so basically the bug is that V1.0 exhibits the  behaviour  one would expect in V2.0?

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242368225968716/ (May 8, 2014 at 4:34pm)

This query works for an v1.0 enabled app

`SELECT name,mutual_friend_count FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend where uid2=me()) order by mutual_friend_count`